Anger in Hinduism
In Gita its written anger is bad .wee should not indulge into hatred and anger. So how can we do violence (if needed)without hatred and anger? Any examples.

Mahabharatam (‘Adi Parva’, 11.12, 69) says:

अहिंसा परमॊ धर्मः
ahimsa paramo dharmaḥ
Non-violence is the highest moral virtue.

The Veda too says the following:

mā hinsyāt sarvā bhūtāni
“Do not commit violence toward any living entity.”

Unless absolutely necessary in an extreme situation (such as to fight against Adharma), violence in any form is a sin and non-violence a superior virtue.
Example: Krishna, Bhīma, and Arjuna together approached King Jarāsandha(जरासन्ध) of Magadha and challenged him to a fight. Jarāsandha chose Bhīma for a duel. Subsequently Bhīma slayed Jarāsandha.

Observe that the violence (killing) was carried out without hatred and anger in order to establish Dharma.

